# Azure VIP swap down time

Tags: azure

every time I do a VIP swap in Azure I have downtime. Note that I've **warmed up the staging fully** (through navigating manually to the staging IP and click around).

Then I do a VIP swap, and I have a very long downtime, varying from 30 seconds to in some cases three minutes.

This is of course quite a horrible user experience. Think about that you're at the point of doing an online buy and then suddenly the site doesn't respond the next two minutes. Gone customer.

As I don't read much about complaints I'm wondering what's up?

- Could it be something that is dependent one my specific 'Cloud service'? The service is already three years old, maybe stuff has been fixed since then?
- Could this be dependent on the cloud center I use? That only people that use West Europe have these problems, limiting the amount of complaints?
- Could this be something related to Sql Azure? I'm seeing also lost connections during the VIP swap.
- Or do people think this is normal behaviour and just accept it?

PS: for the rest Azure is seriously fantastic.

Comment: Some of my customers says that it takes over 30 minutes for the swap to complete, thus they always do the swap after hours at night, they also show a "down for maintenance" page and truncate all connected users off, once all connections are gone from their services, they do the actual swap. it could be harder to do this if you have a lot of users connected, but just sharing the experience.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to Azure support.

Comment: Note that existing browser connections will still be connected to the old deployment after a VIP swap.  Due to browser HTTP keep-alives, these connections can hang around for quite a while.

Comment: @fukawi2, too bad, because I want to put an answer that actually can help people having the same problems - switch to the new Azure Web App.